# Bean validation with hibernate in karaf, cxf and dosgi

Tags: osgi, cxf, hibernate-validator, karaf, dosgi

I have jax-rs services exposed in Karaf with cxf dosgi. I am trying to add bean validation with a hibernate provider.

1. I Installed the hibernate-validator feature
2. I Installed the cxf-bean-validation and cxf-bean-validation-core features although I am not sure whether they are both needed.
3. I added the following intent to enable the hibernate provider:

   ```
   @Component(immediate = true, property = "org.apache.cxf.dosgi.IntentName=bean-validation")
   public class BeanValidationIntent implements Callable<List<Object>>  {

   @Override
   public List<Object> call() throws Exception {

       List<Object> list = new ArrayList<Object>();

       BeanValidationFeature beanValidationFeature = new BeanValidationFeature();
       beanValidationFeature.setProvider(new BeanValidationProvider(new HibernateValidationProviderResolver()));

       list.add(beanValidationFeature);

       return list;
   }
   ```

   }

But I am getting the exception in the bottom. I added the bundle (wrapped) which contains the missing class:

```
install -s wrap:mvn:com.sun.el/el-ri/1.0
```

This still doesn't solve the problem.

I am using karaf 4.0.8

Please share if you have any idea! Thanks!!

```
Caused by:

java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at org.hibernate.validator.messageinterpolation.ResourceBundleMessageInterpolator.interpolateExpression(ResourceBundleMessageInterpolator.java:227)
    at org.hibernate.validator.messageinterpolation.ResourceBundleMessageInterpolator.interpolateMessage(ResourceBundleMessageInterpolator.java:187)
    at org.hibernate.validator.messageinterpolation.ResourceBundleMessageInterpolator.interpolate(ResourceBundleMessageInterpolator.java:115)
    at org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.ValidationContext.interpolate(ValidationContext.java:370)
    at org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.ValidationContext.createConstraintViolation(ValidationContext.java:284)
    at org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.ValidationContext.createConstraintViolations(ValidationContext.java:246)
    at org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.constraintvalidation.ConstraintTree.validateSingleConstraint(ConstraintTree.java:289)
    at org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.constraintvalidation.ConstraintTree.validateConstraints(ConstraintTree.java:133)
    at org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.constraintvalidation.ConstraintTree.validateConstraints(ConstraintTree.java:91)
    at org.hibernate.validator.internal.metadata.core.MetaConstraint.validateConstraint(MetaConstraint.java:85)
    at org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.ValidatorImpl.validateConstraintsForGroup(ValidatorImpl.java:1195)
    at org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.ValidatorImpl.validateParametersForGroup(ValidatorImpl.java:1015)
    at org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.ValidatorImpl.validateParametersInContext(ValidatorImpl.java:900)
    at org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.ValidatorImpl.validateParameters(ValidatorImpl.java:240)
    at org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.ValidatorImpl.validateParameters(ValidatorImpl.java:198)
    at org.apache.cxf.validation.BeanValidationProvider.validateParameters(BeanValidationProvider.java:116)
    at org.apache.cxf.validation.BeanValidationInInterceptor.handleValidation(BeanValidationInInterceptor.java:59)
    at org.apache.cxf.validation.AbstractValidationInterceptor.handleMessage(AbstractValidationInterceptor.java:72)
    at org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain.doIntercept(PhaseInterceptorChain.java:308)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.ChainInitiationObserver.onMessage(ChainInitiationObserver.java:121)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.AbstractHTTPDestination.invoke(AbstractHTTPDestination.java:254)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.ServletController.invokeDestination(ServletController.java:234)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.ServletController.invoke(ServletController.java:208)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.ServletController.invoke(ServletController.java:160)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.CXFNonSpringServlet.invoke(CXFNonSpringServlet.java:180)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.AbstractHTTPServlet.handleRequest(AbstractHTTPServlet.java:299)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.AbstractHTTPServlet.doGet(AbstractHTTPServlet.java:223)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:687)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.AbstractHTTPServlet.service(AbstractHTTPServlet.java:274)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:812)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:587)
    at org.ops4j.pax.web.service.jetty.internal.HttpServiceServletHandler.doHandle(HttpServiceServletHandler.java:71)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:143)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:577)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:223)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1127)
    at org.ops4j.pax.web.service.jetty.internal.HttpServiceContext.doHandle(HttpServiceContext.java:287)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:515)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:185)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1061)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:141)
    at org.ops4j.pax.web.service.jetty.internal.JettyServerHandlerCollection.handle(JettyServerHandlerCollection.java:80)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:97)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:499)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.handle(HttpChannel.java:311)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.onFillable(HttpConnection.java:257)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$2.run(AbstractConnection.java:544)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:635)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$3.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:555)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: javax.el.ELException: Provider com.sun.el.ExpressionFactoryImpl not found
    at javax.el.FactoryFinder.newInstance(FactoryFinder.java:101)
    at javax.el.FactoryFinder.find(FactoryFinder.java:197)
    at javax.el.ExpressionFactory.newInstance(ExpressionFactory.java:189)
    at javax.el.ExpressionFactory.newInstance(ExpressionFactory.java:160)
    at org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.messageinterpolation.InterpolationTerm.<clinit>(InterpolationTerm.java:60)
    ... 50 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.sun.el.ExpressionFactoryImpl not found by org.apache.cxf.dosgi.cxf-dosgi-common [172]
    at org.apache.felix.framework.BundleWiringImpl.findClassOrResourceByDelegation(BundleWiringImpl.java:1574)
    at org.apache.felix.framework.BundleWiringImpl.access$400(BundleWiringImpl.java:79)
    at org.apache.felix.framework.BundleWiringImpl$BundleClassLoader.loadClass(BundleWiringImpl.java:2018)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.loadBundleClass(Felix.java:1925)
    at org.apache.felix.framework.BundleImpl.loadClass(BundleImpl.java:978)
    at org.ops4j.pax.swissbox.core.BundleClassLoader.findClass(BundleClassLoader.java:176)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at org.ops4j.pax.swissbox.core.BundleClassLoader.loadClass(BundleClassLoader.java:192)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    at javax.el.FactoryFinder.newInstance(FactoryFinder.java:87)
    ... 54 more
Caused by:

javax.el.ELException: Provider com.sun.el.ExpressionFactoryImpl not found
    at javax.el.FactoryFinder.newInstance(FactoryFinder.java:101)
    at javax.el.FactoryFinder.find(FactoryFinder.java:197)
    at javax.el.ExpressionFactory.newInstance(ExpressionFactory.java:189)
    at javax.el.ExpressionFactory.newInstance(ExpressionFactory.java:160)
    at org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.messageinterpolation.InterpolationTerm.<clinit>(InterpolationTerm.java:60)
    at org.hibernate.validator.messageinterpolation.ResourceBundleMessageInterpolator.interpolateExpression(ResourceBundleMessageInterpolator.java:227)
    at org.hibernate.validator.messageinterpolation.ResourceBundleMessageInterpolator.interpolateMessage(ResourceBundleMessageInterpolator.java:187)
    at org.hibernate.validator.messageinterpolation.ResourceBundleMessageInterpolator.interpolate(ResourceBundleMessageInterpolator.java:115)
    at org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.ValidationContext.interpolate(ValidationContext.java:370)
    at org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.ValidationContext.createConstraintViolation(ValidationContext.java:284)
    at org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.ValidationContext.createConstraintViolations(ValidationContext.java:246)
    at org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.constraintvalidation.ConstraintTree.validateSingleConstraint(ConstraintTree.java:289)
    at org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.constraintvalidation.ConstraintTree.validateConstraints(ConstraintTree.java:133)
    at org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.constraintvalidation.ConstraintTree.validateConstraints(ConstraintTree.java:91)
    at org.hibernate.validator.internal.metadata.core.MetaConstraint.validateConstraint(MetaConstraint.java:85)
    at org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.ValidatorImpl.validateConstraintsForGroup(ValidatorImpl.java:1195)
    at org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.ValidatorImpl.validateParametersForGroup(ValidatorImpl.java:1015)
    at org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.ValidatorImpl.validateParametersInContext(ValidatorImpl.java:900)
    at org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.ValidatorImpl.validateParameters(ValidatorImpl.java:240)
    at org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.ValidatorImpl.validateParameters(ValidatorImpl.java:198)
    at org.apache.cxf.validation.BeanValidationProvider.validateParameters(BeanValidationProvider.java:116)
    at org.apache.cxf.validation.BeanValidationInInterceptor.handleValidation(BeanValidationInInterceptor.java:59)
    at org.apache.cxf.validation.AbstractValidationInterceptor.handleMessage(AbstractValidationInterceptor.java:72)
    at org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain.doIntercept(PhaseInterceptorChain.java:308)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.ChainInitiationObserver.onMessage(ChainInitiationObserver.java:121)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.AbstractHTTPDestination.invoke(AbstractHTTPDestination.java:254)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.ServletController.invokeDestination(ServletController.java:234)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.ServletController.invoke(ServletController.java:208)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.ServletController.invoke(ServletController.java:160)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.CXFNonSpringServlet.invoke(CXFNonSpringServlet.java:180)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.AbstractHTTPServlet.handleRequest(AbstractHTTPServlet.java:299)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.AbstractHTTPServlet.doGet(AbstractHTTPServlet.java:223)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:687)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.AbstractHTTPServlet.service(AbstractHTTPServlet.java:274)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:812)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:587)
    at org.ops4j.pax.web.service.jetty.internal.HttpServiceServletHandler.doHandle(HttpServiceServletHandler.java:71)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:143)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:577)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:223)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1127)
    at org.ops4j.pax.web.service.jetty.internal.HttpServiceContext.doHandle(HttpServiceContext.java:287)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:515)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:185)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1061)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:141)
    at org.ops4j.pax.web.service.jetty.internal.JettyServerHandlerCollection.handle(JettyServerHandlerCollection.java:80)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:97)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:499)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.handle(HttpChannel.java:311)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.onFillable(HttpConnection.java:257)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$2.run(AbstractConnection.java:544)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:635)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$3.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:555)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.sun.el.ExpressionFactoryImpl not found by org.apache.cxf.dosgi.cxf-dosgi-common [172]
    at org.apache.felix.framework.BundleWiringImpl.findClassOrResourceByDelegation(BundleWiringImpl.java:1574)
    at org.apache.felix.framework.BundleWiringImpl.access$400(BundleWiringImpl.java:79)
    at org.apache.felix.framework.BundleWiringImpl$BundleClassLoader.loadClass(BundleWiringImpl.java:2018)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.loadBundleClass(Felix.java:1925)
    at org.apache.felix.framework.BundleImpl.loadClass(BundleImpl.java:978)
    at org.ops4j.pax.swissbox.core.BundleClassLoader.findClass(BundleClassLoader.java:176)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at org.ops4j.pax.swissbox.core.BundleClassLoader.loadClass(BundleClassLoader.java:192)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    at javax.el.FactoryFinder.newInstance(FactoryFinder.java:87)
    ... 54 more
Caused by:

java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.sun.el.ExpressionFactoryImpl not found by org.apache.cxf.dosgi.cxf-dosgi-common [172]
    at org.apache.felix.framework.BundleWiringImpl.findClassOrResourceByDelegation(BundleWiringImpl.java:1574)
    at org.apache.felix.framework.BundleWiringImpl.access$400(BundleWiringImpl.java:79)
    at org.apache.felix.framework.BundleWiringImpl$BundleClassLoader.loadClass(BundleWiringImpl.java:2018)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.loadBundleClass(Felix.java:1925)
    at org.apache.felix.framework.BundleImpl.loadClass(BundleImpl.java:978)
    at org.ops4j.pax.swissbox.core.BundleClassLoader.findClass(BundleClassLoader.java:176)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at org.ops4j.pax.swissbox.core.BundleClassLoader.loadClass(BundleClassLoader.java:192)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    at javax.el.FactoryFinder.newInstance(FactoryFinder.java:87)
    at javax.el.FactoryFinder.find(FactoryFinder.java:197)
    at javax.el.ExpressionFactory.newInstance(ExpressionFactory.java:189)
    at javax.el.ExpressionFactory.newInstance(ExpressionFactory.java:160)
    at org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.messageinterpolation.InterpolationTerm.<clinit>(InterpolationTerm.java:60)
    at org.hibernate.validator.messageinterpolation.ResourceBundleMessageInterpolator.interpolateExpression(ResourceBundleMessageInterpolator.java:227)
    at org.hibernate.validator.messageinterpolation.ResourceBundleMessageInterpolator.interpolateMessage(ResourceBundleMessageInterpolator.java:187)
    at org.hibernate.validator.messageinterpolation.ResourceBundleMessageInterpolator.interpolate(ResourceBundleMessageInterpolator.java:115)
    at org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.ValidationContext.interpolate(ValidationContext.java:370)
    at org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.ValidationContext.createConstraintViolation(ValidationContext.java:284)
    at org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.ValidationContext.createConstraintViolations(ValidationContext.java:246)
    at org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.constraintvalidation.ConstraintTree.validateSingleConstraint(ConstraintTree.java:289)
    at org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.constraintvalidation.ConstraintTree.validateConstraints(ConstraintTree.java:133)
    at org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.constraintvalidation.ConstraintTree.validateConstraints(ConstraintTree.java:91)
    at org.hibernate.validator.internal.metadata.core.MetaConstraint.validateConstraint(MetaConstraint.java:85)
    at org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.ValidatorImpl.validateConstraintsForGroup(ValidatorImpl.java:1195)
    at org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.ValidatorImpl.validateParametersForGroup(ValidatorImpl.java:1015)
    at org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.ValidatorImpl.validateParametersInContext(ValidatorImpl.java:900)
    at org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.ValidatorImpl.validateParameters(ValidatorImpl.java:240)
    at org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.ValidatorImpl.validateParameters(ValidatorImpl.java:198)
    at org.apache.cxf.validation.BeanValidationProvider.validateParameters(BeanValidationProvider.java:116)
    at org.apache.cxf.validation.BeanValidationInInterceptor.handleValidation(BeanValidationInInterceptor.java:59)
    at org.apache.cxf.validation.AbstractValidationInterceptor.handleMessage(AbstractValidationInterceptor.java:72)
    at org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain.doIntercept(PhaseInterceptorChain.java:308)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.ChainInitiationObserver.onMessage(ChainInitiationObserver.java:121)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.AbstractHTTPDestination.invoke(AbstractHTTPDestination.java:254)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.ServletController.invokeDestination(ServletController.java:234)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.ServletController.invoke(ServletController.java:208)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.ServletController.invoke(ServletController.java:160)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.CXFNonSpringServlet.invoke(CXFNonSpringServlet.java:180)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.AbstractHTTPServlet.handleRequest(AbstractHTTPServlet.java:299)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.AbstractHTTPServlet.doGet(AbstractHTTPServlet.java:223)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:687)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.AbstractHTTPServlet.service(AbstractHTTPServlet.java:274)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:812)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:587)
    at org.ops4j.pax.web.service.jetty.internal.HttpServiceServletHandler.doHandle(HttpServiceServletHandler.java:71)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:143)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:577)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:223)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1127)
    at org.ops4j.pax.web.service.jetty.internal.HttpServiceContext.doHandle(HttpServiceContext.java:287)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:515)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:185)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1061)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:141)
    at org.ops4j.pax.web.service.jetty.internal.JettyServerHandlerCollection.handle(JettyServerHandlerCollection.java:80)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:97)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:499)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.handle(HttpChannel.java:311)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.onFillable(HttpConnection.java:257)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$2.run(AbstractConnection.java:544)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:635)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$3.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:555)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Answer (score 0):

The EL ExpressionFactory initialization is a bit buggy: it uses the TCCL instead of using its own class loader and our Karaf feature does not import com.sun.el as it shouldn't be necessary.

We introduced the externalClassLoader() method in HV to (among other things) work around this issue.

See how we do use it in our OSGi integration tests:
https://github.com/hibernate/hibernate-validator/blob/5.4/osgi/integrationtest/src/test/java/org/hibernate/validator/osgi/integrationtest/OsgiIntegrationTest.java#L139

(Note that in 5.4, you also need the providerResolver() call - this limitation is removed in the soon to be coming 6.0)

Comment: Thanks for sharing! That solved the problem. Note that I had to add an import-package for 'com.sun.el' in my OSGi bundle for this to work. The only problem I still have is that I can no longer use the out-of-the-box CXF validation interceptors. But I can always write my own interceptors.